# How to get video content from framebuffer (/dev/graphics/fb0)?

Tags: android, framebuffer, android-ndk-r5

I am accessing (`framebuffer`) `fb0` file from native code and successfully able to get image content with `fb0`. But if I play a video or open the camera, it gives me black screen.

At that time if I rotate the screen, it gives some images of video, again it goes to black display.

Can somebody help to know how to access video data from `framebuffer` or also want to know the reason why it is displaying images at time of screen rotation?

Comment: Did you try to invalidate the view each time a buffer is received ?

Comment: I am drawing it on PC application

Comment: Reading the screen contents in this way is not officially supported and the behaviour should therefore be considered as undefined. See e.g. [this post on the android-ndk discussion list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-ndk/j438Uyfmy78)

Comment: But many applications using it.